# How to determine if nextjs children are strings

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

Before upgrading to next 13 code was working fine now I get this typescript error in vsode, buttonProps is of type type 'ReactI18NextChild | Iterable'. Stack overflow said I have to add more detail because my post is mainly code.

> Argument of type 'ReactI18NextChild | Iterable' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ReactNode | ReactNode[]'.

```
import React, { ButtonHTMLAttributes } from 'react';
import { ReactI18NextChild } from 'react-i18next';
import { parseBackgroundColor, parseColor, parseBorderColor, parseFontSize } from 'styles/styles';

interface Props extends ButtonHTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement> {
    otherProps
}

function Button({ otherProps, ...buttonProps }: Props) {
    const isString = React.Children.toArray(buttonProps.children).some(child => {
      if (
        typeof child === 'string' ||
        typeof child === 'number' ||
        ((child as any)?.type && ['span', 'p', 'h1', 'h2', 'h3', 'h4', 'h5', 'h6'].includes((child as any).type))
      ) {
        return true;
      }
    });

    return <button>{buttonProps.children}</button>
}
```

All packages have been updated to latest.

```
"dependencies": {
    "@aws-amplify/datastore": "^4.0.1",
    "@aws-sdk/util-credentials": "^3.56.0",
    "@capacitor/core": "^4.4.0",
    "@capacitor/device": "^4.0.1",
    "@react-pdf/renderer": "^3.0.1",
    "array-move": "^4.0.0",
    "aws-amplify": "5.0.1",
    "clsx": "^1.2.1",
    "crypto-js": "^4.1.1",
    "graphql-tag": "^2.12.6",
    "i18next": "^21.10.0",
    "i18next-locize-backend": "^6.0.0",
    "immer": "^9.0.16",
    "intl-tel-input": "^17.0.19",
    "ksuid": "^3.0.0",
    "locize-cli": "^7.12.8",
    "logrocket": "^3.0.1",
    "logrocket-react": "^5.0.1",
    "next": "^13.0.3",
    "next-pwa": "^5.6.0",
    "qrcode.react": "^3.1.0",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-datepicker": "^4.7.0",
    "react-dnd": "^16.0.1",
    "react-dnd-html5-backend": "^16.0.1",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-google-charts": "^4.0.0",
    "react-i18next": "12.0.0",
    "react-indiana-drag-scroll": "^2.1.0",
    "react-loader-spinner": "^6.0.0-0",
    "react-query": "^3.39.2",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "react-simple-keyboard": "^3.4.237",
    "sharp": "^0.31.2",
    "universal-cookie": "^4.0.4",
    "zustand": "^4.1.4"   },   "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/helper-call-delegate": "^7.12.1",
    "@types/crypto-js": "^4.0.2",
    "@types/intl-tel-input": "^17.0.6",
    "@types/logrocket-react": "^3.0.0",
    "@types/node": "18.11.9",
    "@types/qrcode.react": "^1.0.1",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.25",
    "@types/react-datepicker": "^4.8.0",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.9",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "5.43.0",
    "@welldone-software/why-did-you-render": "^7.0.1",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.13",
    "eslint": "8.27.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "13.0.3",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.5.0",
    "husky": "^8.0.2",
    "lint-staged": "^13.0.3",
    "postcss": "^8.4.19",
    "prettier": "^2.6.1",
    "stylelint": "^14.15.0",
    "stylelint-config-prettier": "^9.0.4",
    "stylelint-config-standard": "^29.0.0",
    "stylelint-config-tailwindcss": "^0.0.7",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.2.4",
    "typescript": "4.9.3"   } }
```

Comment: where is that error shown? What is the type of `buttonProps.children?`

Comment: type is  'ReactI18NextChild | Iterable<ReactI18NextChild>'.  error is in vscode.

Comment: Can you try updating your `react` dependency? Try `18.2.0` for `react` (maybe for `react-dom` too)

Comment: everything is latest, react and react-dom are 18.2.0

Comment: can you share your package.json?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this error is the type definition of `react-i18next`. There are certain `interface` augmentations inside the `react-i18next` type definition files which override existing types.

The problematic bit is here:

```
type ObjectOrNever = TypeOptions['allowObjectInHTMLChildren'] extends true
  ? Record<string, unknown>
  : never;
type ReactI18NextChild = React.ReactNode | ObjectOrNever;

declare module 'react' {
  interface HTMLAttributes<T> {
    children?: ReactI18NextChild | Iterable<ReactI18NextChild>;
  }
}
```

For some reason, `children` are overwritten to be of type `ReactI18NextChild | Iterable<ReactI18NextChild>`. And `ReactI18NextChild` includes this `ObjectOrNever` type in the union which has a possible `Record<string, unknown>` output type. And `Record<string, unknown>` is not assignable to `React.ReactNode` causing the error.

I would personally advise to just use a type assertion for now:

```
const isString = React.Children.toArray(
  buttonProps.children as React.ReactNode
).some(child => {
  /* ... */
});
```

Or to completely remove the `react-i18next` import, if possible.

Either way, you may open an issue on Github about this. This may or may not be the indented behavior especially if this worked before the update.

Comment: ok thank you, I did end up adding `as React.ReactNode`